# Python - read from serial port and encode as JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization, arduino

I've burned way too much time on this but just cannot figure it out. I have an arduino that writes a json string to the serial port. The string looks like this : {"temp":"69","light":"141","z":"999"} and validates as valid json. I am trying to use the following python script to read from the serial port and print out the various values of the json string.

```
import serial
import json

serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, timeout=1)
while True:
 data = serial.readline().strip('\n\r')
 j = json.loads(data)
 print(data)
 print j['temp']
```

No matter what I try to change I end up with this error message: *No JSON object could be decoded.* Yet, this works perfectly:

```
import json

data = '{"temp":"95","light":"200","z":"999"}'
j = json.loads(data)
print(data)
print j['temp']
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Move the `print(data)` call above the line that's erroring so you can see what you're getting. And `print(repr(data))` might give you a better idea of what's actually in the data.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `data` is a valid JSON string? Try printing it out _before_ you try to parse it with `json.loads`.

Comment: What happens when `data` is a blank line?

Comment: It sounds too me like you're trying to parse the json output before it's finished reading. Why not move the `json.loads(data)` outside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

Because you're specifying a (read)timeout to your serial object, the `readline` method might return an empty string if it couldn't find a `\n` before the timeout was reached. This would indeed result in the error you're describing:

```
In [18]: import json

In [19]: json.loads('')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
[ stripping extra output - merely an example ]

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Make sure your Arduino is sending the stream of characters terminated with a newline character. If your Arduino code uses `Serial.println(yourJSONdata)` instead of `Serial.print(val)` then it should be taken care of automatically.

Alternatively, parse the serial input buffer one character at a time (`Serial.read(1)`), for example like this (remark: it's not very efficient):

```
input = [' ']
while input[-1] != '}':
    input.append(serial.read(1))
data = ''.join(input)
j = json.loads(data)
```

Sending the newline character is now not needed.
Note that this code will fail if you nest dictionaries, in which case you need to keep track of the nesting level. Looking at the contents of your Arduino-returned string, I guess you're reading out simple sensor data in which case a single nesting level is probably more than enough.

Also, I'd consider it bad form to use the module name as a variable, thereby making it unaccessible. You could use `from serial import Serial` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert  the received bytes to string by using the "dot  encode()" method then continue with your json data